# Hashing tag list to perform faster search

Tags: algorithms, search, hashing

I have a list of items. Each item have various properties. Each item can be tagged, like tagging a post here. Right now, tags are represented using a `Tags` property, that is a string and it looks like `tag1:tag2:...:tagN`.

A user can search for an item based on its tags (i.e. get me items that has `tag2` and `tagN`).
To do this I need to scan the full items list and, even worst I need to split the `Tags` property and search if those tags are present.

What I'm searching for is a sort of hashing filter or a better algorithm to perform this type of search. Note that, if searching for `tag2` would mean *give me items with just tag2* the search would be simpler, alas what this really means is  *give me items that contains tag2*, so splitting (at least, for now) is mandatory.

We would change the representation from `tag1:tag2:...:tagN` to a better one, in order to provide a faster search. Possibly without a lookup structure or something like that.

Comment: You're giving too little context to decide. Are the tags stored in  database (then it would almost certainly a good idea to use a linking table rather than a compound attribute)? Are they manipulated in the frontend? Then your language might have a regexp substring search that is good enough. But as it is, we can't tell.

Comment: Once you group by tag, searching by a single tag is trivial.  Searching by multiple tags means performing a union/intersection between two sets.   If you search by other fields, do so after you've searched by tag, since you can eliminate plenty that way.

Answer (score 2):

Having `Tags` as string forces you to parse it ever and ever again for every `Item` and for every search. If the tags do not appear in a predefined order, you'd also need to traverse it several times.

#### Improvements at item level

**Improvement 1:**  make `Tags` an ordered list of strings. If you search for several tags then order them as well.  You'd then traverse the Tags searching for the first tag.  If it is found you can continue with the second tag (starting at the next item).

**Improvement 2:** make `Tags` a set of strings. Then it's even more efficient because your language/library will make use of an efficient access to elements, certainly in *O(log n)*.  Most languages even offer  some kind of hash sets that allow an *O(1)* access (e.g. C++ [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), java [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)  or C# [`HashSet`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)).

**Improvement 3:** instead of hashing the same search tag strings for every single item, manage tags as an integer key, using a dictionary to map the tag strings to the tag keys.  So `Tags` would end up as set of `Tag`

#### Improvements at collection level:

Until now, we just improved the performance of searching tags in an item.  However, all these solutions still did require that every single item is searched.

**Improvement 4:**  Make `Tag` and `Item` be related entities that impelment bidirectional navigability. So `Item` would still have a set of tags, but each `Tag` would have a collection of `Item`.  This significantly prunes the search space: order the tag list from the one with the smallest collection of items to the larges.  Look for the items in the collection of the first one.  Then go through the items found to look if they match the others.

**Improvement 5:** You could as well make intersections between several collections (especially if they are ordered).  However, if you have very large lists of items.

#### If you have huge collections

The approach proposed work all very well, but were more conceived for in-memory processing.  If you have huge number of items and tag, you may need a db.

If you use a relational DB, the relation between tags and items (many to many association) will be a table of its own.  The good news is that the db engine will optimize these kind of searches using similar strategies and even more elaborate ones, so that it will be ultra-efficient.